# c# TrimEnd -1 removes last character plus preceding characters if they are repeating

Tags: c#, string, repeat

I want to simply remove the last character of a string that is of an undefined length.  This is what I have:

```
var str = txtBx1.Text;
txtBx2.Text = (str.TrimEnd(str[str.Length - 1]));
```

It works great, when the last two characters are unique. However, when the last two or more characters are the same, all of the repeating characters are removed.

If `txtBx1.Text = '123456789'`  then `txtBx2.Text` will be '12345678'

If `txtBx1.Text = '199999999'`  then `txtBx2.Text` will be '1'; it needs to be '19999999'

How can I simply remove the last character of a string that is of an undefined length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substring:

```
str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Substring` method

```
txtBx2.Text = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
```